# Does Ubuntu installation create folders automatically when using mounts on logical volumes to folders that do not exist yet?

Tags: partitioning, mount, 22.04, lvm

I'm currently installing a new Ubuntu 22.04, and I have the following structure:

```
| Volume Group - VG_SSD                                      |
|     Default Logical Volumes we are used to:                |
|          lv-root - /root, lv-var /var, lv-home /home...    |
|     Non-Default Logical Volume:                            |
|          lv-data - /mnt/data                               |
```

By default, on Debian, Ubuntu, and other distros, the following folder ***DOES NOT*** exist:

> /mnt/data

So, creating a mounting point to a folder that does not exist, without the "NoFail" option, could lead to a system crash and a boot problem. At least, this is what happens when mounting to a folder that does not exist on ***already running Linux distros.***

But i never tried doing this on a fresh install (When manually creating the partition table.)

So, before i proceed, can someone clarify if the install will create the folders/sub-folders automatically, or do i need to do something before?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just test it in a VM?

Comment: I'm trying it right now. Let's hope it does create the folders automatically.